# Lag fixing using OCLF - could it do any harm?

Tags: loopback, ext2

I am wondering if the lag fix proposed by xda-developers could harm the device in anyway.
Quote from Google Code "Original use was for 'One Click Lag Fix' for the Samsung Galaxy S series, to create a loopback EXT2 device on top of Samsung's RFS in order to improve response time for applications."

Link to forum page about this: [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=784691).

How does it work exactly? What does "create loopback EXT2" mean?

I know the forum post clearly states it's been tested on a huge number of devices and it's working, but I want to understand what it does exactly and if there is any compromise by installing it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, it tricks the Android OS by using symbolic links and a large file formatted as ext2, rather than partitioning or formatting your device storage.  In this way it's very safe.  I've used it several times on several ROMs on my Galaxy S with no problems.

Comment: Thank you, Matthew. I'll give it a try then. Out of curiosity, if it's such a great solution why isn't it adopted by Google for future releases? This is me trying to understand if there are no strings attached / compromises and only good will come of it. :)

Comment: @Francisc: because it is basically a hack to allow you to use ext2 without repartitioning the device. This means there is two file system drivers to manage a single partition, the ext2 driver and rfs driver. Even though there are two drivers in play, the hack is a still gain since ext2 driver is much more efficient at managing files than rfs. Google would never adopt such a hack, they instead would simply partition the flash storage using ext4, which they did in Nexus S.